# Unit testing of json encoding/decoding against errors

Tags: php, json, phpunit

So basically I have the code which is giving me the message from json_last_error():

```
$msg = 'Unknown error';
switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        $msg = null;
        break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        $msg = 'Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        $msg = 'Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        $msg = 'Unexpected control character found';
        break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        $msg = 'Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        $msg = 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
}
return $msg;
```

For testing purposes I want to raise all the errors from this list to have 100% coverage, but I can't raise `JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH`.

Can anyone help giving me the example with either encoding or decoding, with any parameters, which can produce this error?

Comment: Just to make things clear: you're unit testing php's native `json_encode()` implementation?

Comment: I think they've got it covered - https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/json/tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$j = '{"j": 1 ] }';

json_decode($j);

var_dump(json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH); // true
```

How I found it: just checked the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/json/JSON_parser.c#L222) :-)

Comment: Legend! Thanks a lot - I will accept in few minutes.

Comment: Link is 404. Please use a [permalink](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/#press-y-to-permalink-to-a-file-in-a-specific-commit) next time

Comment: Possible fit is https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c34de0b61c68bd77e324b869760a53abead4c5ed/ext/json/tests/007.phpt