# How to get various values for json_last_error

Tags: php, json

I'm writing unit tests against a function inspired by [Fastest way to check if a string is JSON in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041741/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-json-in-php#6041773)

For example, I've tried adding control characters to the JSON strings in order to get `json_last_error` to equal `JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR` but it isn't working.  It "does" give an error in JSON but it's seemingly always `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`.  I've done some research but not sure how to make it fail in certain ways.

How might I change the JSON strings below in order to make `json_last_error` evaluate to something other than `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` or `JSON_ERROR_NONE`?

```
$json = '[{user_id":"\x0230", "username":"stack"},{"user_id":14,"username":"over"}]';
$json = '[{"user_id":"\t\\r\\n", "username":"stack"},{"user_id":14,"username":"over"}]';
```

Thanks in advance, Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a `JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR` like this:

```
$json = chr(0).'[{"user_id":"13", "username":"stack"},{"user_id":14,"username":"over"}]';
```

FYI, it appears to give the same error regardless of where the `chr(0)` is in the string, and it works for at least `chr(0)` - `chr(31)`, except 9, 10, and 13.

Comment: Also found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24543526/2734189) that gets a `JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH`.

Comment: @dont-panic, I tried both your answer (to get the ctrl char) and the comment link for `state mismatch` error and both worked great.  In addition, I was able to remove the numeric case in the switch block!. Cheers, and thanks much.

Comment: Have tried to find an example to trip the `JSON_ERROR_UTF8` case but so far the one on the manual page didn't seem to work

Comment: Got it working (the check for bad UTF-8) by taking a string that had UTF-8 and passing it through `utf_decode` function.  When it got checked for its JSON correctness... it failed due to invalid UTF.  For possible future use... this should fail to be valid JSON: `$json   = '[{"condition":"très agréable","explanation":"â€ grÃ¡ficos\xB1\x31"}]';
        $json   = utf8_decode($json);`